# Linq query to pick up field if it is null or matches specific value

Tags: .net, linq

I'm trying to write a Linq query that checks three fields: `StateCode`, `ChannelCode`, and `ZipCode`.

I want to check for an exact match on State and Channel Code. However, if the record in the database happens to be null, then I want to pull that record. If it is not null, I want to pull it only if the zip code matches a value. I've tried to write this a couple different ways and each keeps failing. Here's my most recent attempt:

```
var similarZips = (from z in _db.ZipCodeTerritory
                    where z.StateCode.Equals(zipCode.StateCode) &&
                            z.ChannelCode.Equals(zipCode.ChannelCode)
                    select z).Where(x => x.Id != zipCode.Id && 
                            (x.ZipCode.Equals(null) || x.ZipCode.Equals(zipCode.ZipCode))).ToList();
```

I also gave this a shot and received the same results

```
var similarZips = (from z in _db.ZipCodeTerritory
                    where z.StateCode.Equals(zipCode.StateCode) &&
                            z.ChannelCode.Equals(zipCode.ChannelCode) &&
                            (z.ZipCode.Equals(null) ? z.ZipCode.Equals(null) : z.ZipCode.Equals(zipCode.ZipCode))
                    select z).Where(x => x.Id != zipCode.Id).ToList();
```

**EDIT**

The problem happening here occurs only when the `zipCode.ZipCode` value is `NULL`. In that case, this statement is redundant `x.ZipCode.Equals(null) || x.ZipCode.Equals(zipCode.ZipCode)` - I'm basically asking it to check for a `null` or something that `.Equal(null)`.

I need to re-write the query similar to below. The problem I'm having, however, is now in the first part of the ternary statement. If the `zipCode.Zipcode` value is null, then I simply want to grab all records with a matching state and channel code combo (any zip will do). However, if the zip is defined then I only want to grab state/channel combos with either a matching zip code or a null zip code. I'm stuck on the part where, if the `zipCode.ZipCode` value is `null` I tell the query to grab all records.

```
 var similarZips = (from z in _db.ZipCodeTerritory
                    where z.StateCode.Equals(zipCode.StateCode) &&
                            z.ChannelCode.Equals(zipCode.ChannelCode) && 
                            (zipCode.ZipCode.Equals(null) ? 
                                    <any zip will do> : 
                                (z.ZipCode.Equals(zipCode.ZipCode) || z.ZipCode.Equals(null)))
                    select z).Where(x => x.Id != zipCode.Id).ToList();**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cant you just use two queries?

```
List<ZipCodeTerritory> similarZips;

if (zipCode.ZipCode != null)
{
  similarZips = (from z in _db.ZipCodeTerritory
                 where z.StateCode.Equals(zipCode.StateCode) &&
                       z.ChannelCode.Equals(zipCode.ChannelCode) &&
                       z.ZipCode.Equals(zipCode.ZipCode)).ToList(); 
}
else
{
  similarZips = (from z in _db.ZipCodeTerritory
                 where z.StateCode.Equals(zipCode.StateCode) &&
                       z.ChannelCode.Equals(zipCode.ChannelCode).ToList(); 

}
```

Comment: This seems to handle the first case incorrectly - if a ZIP code is specified only records with a matching ZIP code are retrieved but records with a null ZIP code are omitted while they should be included if I understand the question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Since I guess Linq doesn't have a keyword for "all" I had to write the query like this

```
var similarZips = (from z in _db.ZipCodeTerritory
                    where (zipCode.ZipCode.Equals(null) ?
                            z.StateCode.Equals(zipCode.StateCode) &&
                            z.ChannelCode.Equals(zipCode.ChannelCode) :
                            z.StateCode.Equals(zipCode.StateCode) &&
                            z.ChannelCode.Equals(zipCode.ChannelCode) &&
                            (z.ZipCode.Equals(zipcodeterritory.ZipCode) || z.ZipCode.Equals(null)))
                    select z).Where(x => x.Id != zipCode.Id).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 1      z.StateCode.Equals(zipCode.StateCode)
 2   && z.ChannelCode.Equals(zipCode.ChannelCode)
 3   && (
 4          (zipCode.ZipCode.Equals(null))
 5       ||
 6          (
 7              (!zipCode.ZipCode.Equals(null))
 8           &&
 9              (
10                  z.ZipCode.Equals(null)
11               ||
12                  z.ZipCode.Equals(zipCode.ZipCode)
13              )
14          )
15      )
```

(1) Match state (2) and channel (3) and (4) either there is no ZIP code specified (5) or (7) there is a ZIP code specified (8) and (10) the ZIP code of the record is null (11) or (12) matches the specified ZIP code.

As you can easily see line 7 is redundant and the whole thing can be reduced to the following.

```
   z.StateCode.Equals(zipCode.StateCode)
&& z.ChannelCode.Equals(zipCode.ChannelCode)
&& (
        zipCode.ZipCode.Equals(null)
     || z.ZipCode.Equals(null)
     || z.ZipCode.Equals(zipCode.ZipCode)
   )
```